# Package Dependencies

Tags: r, r-package

I have an R package, that depends on the `base64enc` library. When I run the source file in the package with Rscript:

```
Rscript analyzer.R
```

it runs just fine.

The first line in analyzer.R is:

```
library(base64enc);
```

However, when I run a function from the package in the repl:

```
library(analyzer)
analyze()
```

It complains that base64enc is not installed.

```
Error in rawToChar(base64decode(mark[1])) :
  could not find function "base64decode"
Calls: analyze ... collect.marks -> lapply -> FUN -> lapply -> FUN -> rawToChar
```

However, when in the REPL I manually include base64enc:

```
library(base64enc)
library(analyzer)
analyze()
```

It works fine. Is there anyway I can tell my analyzer package to use the base64enc library without having to include it in every script every time I use the library?

Comment: You should look at the instructions in the [Package Dependencies](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) section of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note that a script is not a package.)

When you run your script `analyzer.R` it explicitly loads `base64enc` so the package is in your load path.

But your package *may* just have `Imports: base64enc` with a corresponding `NAMESPACE` statement -- that makes the code from `base64enc` available in you package *but does not load it*.

Back in the day we used to do `Depends: base64enc` which *would* load it too -- but clutters the search path.  `Imports:` is better, but has the very side-effect you observe here.  So just load the other package at the REPL.